# How do I delete a specific map from firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following setup in google firebase. I named every Map, which means that the map-name for me the index and unique for every document. I'm using Vuejs (Javascript)

```
eQFelbD432T (Collection  Name- user.uid)
  SKILLS (Document Name)
    ProjectManangement (Map Name)
      Rating: 4      (Key - Value Pair)
      Experience: 2  (Key - Value  Pair)
    SystemEngneering (Map Name)
      Rating: 6       (Key - Value Pair)
      Experience: 2   (Key - Value Pair)
```

I would like to delete now one specific map with all the values included but I can't find out how this works since I couldnt find any way to address this specific map.

My code for the moment looks the following - **but it does not work**: **mapName** holds the name of the map which should be deleted (e.g. ProjectManagement) which is delivered by a function.

```
let ref = db.collection(this.$store.getters.getUserId).doc('SKILLS')
ref.get().then(doc => {
  if (doc.exists) {
    ref.update( { [mapName]: FieldValue.delete() } )
  }
})
```

Hope there is someone out there who can help me or maybe I'm to blind to see the obvious solution...

Thanks and best regards

Comment: I suggest hard coding the values of variables so we can see exactly what you're doing.  We can't see the values of `this.$store.getters.getUserId` and `mapName`, so if they're incorrect, we'd never know.  It also would help to show a screenshot of the database so we can also see that the values you pass match exactly what's there.

Comment: I tried that already and logged them over the console, the variables are correct. '''this.$store.getters.getUserId'''  (eQFelbD432T) outputs the userid of the user which will define the collection mapName contents the MapName as a string ("e.g. ProjectManagment"). The data is definitly correct since i load the data before directly from my firebase database. I can easily delete the whole document and i also can set and update the docuemnt with this variables. I "jsut" dont know how the syntax looks to delete a specific Map... Thanks for helping. Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The working code looks like this:

```
ref.get().then(doc => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            ref.update( { [mapName]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete() } )
          }
        })
```

It seems that, to delete a single map, I needed to put the "firebase.firestore." before the FieldValue even I imported firebase (import firebase from 'firebase').

Comment: I would have expected to see an error if you didn't refer to FieldValue correctly.  In the future, please share any errors you get in your question.  Just saying "it does not work" is often not enough information to work with.